# How can I update the listbox

Tags: python, user-interface

I want to make an `updateWidget` function that will clear a listbox after taking the grabbable item (by pressing the "Take" button), and will update the listbox when the play moves to a different room by using the "go east, go south, go west, go north" commands in the input box.

```
def createWidgets(self):
    # create the "Take" button
    self.takeButton = Button(self, text="Take", command=self.takeItem, width=10, height=2, font=("Arial", 16))
    self.takeButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    # create a frame to hold the label and listbox
    itemsFrame = Frame(self)
    itemsFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

    # create the label and listbox widgets
    titleLabel = Label(itemsFrame, text="Grabbable Items", font=("Arial", 18))
    titleLabel.pack()
    self.itemListbox = Listbox(itemsFrame, font=("Arial", 14))
    self.itemListbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

    # add items to the listbox
    for item in self.currentRoom.grabbables:
        self.itemListbox.insert(END, item)

def updateWidget(room, grabbable_items, listbox):
    # clear the listbox
    listbox.delete(0, END)
    
    # add grabbable items to the listbox
    for item in grabbable_items:
        listbox.insert(END, item)
    
    # clear and refill the listbox if room changes
    if room != current_room:
        current_room = room
        listbox.delete(0, END)
        for item in current_room.get_grabbable_items():
            listbox.insert(END, item)

# make an updateWidget function
# clear listbox after taking grabbable
# create a method that clears the listbox and refills after moving to another room


# function that will be called when the "Take" button is clicked
def takeItem(self):
    # get the currently selected item from the listbox
    selected = self.itemListbox.curselection()
    if len(selected) == 0:
        return 
    item = self.itemListbox.get(selected[0])

    # remove the item from the room and add it to the player's inventory
    if item in self.currentRoom.grabbables:
        self.currentRoom.delGrabbable(item)
        self.inventory.append(item)
```

I don't know how to incorporate it into my class and have it constantly update every time the player does something.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use an external list.
Any change done to lbList will automatically modify the displayed  list.

```
lbList = tk.StringVar()
lb = tk.Listbox( root, listvariable=lbList, height=5, width=10)
lb.pack()
myList = ['gold nugget', 'hammer', 'credit card'] # items available here
lbList.set( myList) # update the list
#
del( myList[ lb.curselection()[0]]) # item grabbed
lbList.set( myList) # update the list
#
lbList.set( []) # clear list without using myList
```